# Сортировка многомерного массива

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, c, c++

Подскажите алгоритм (на словах) сортировки массива по элементам третьего столбца.

Comment: Извините, уточните что нужно сортировать и откуда вы такой алгоритм взяли?
я много сортировок знаю, но о такой не слышал...

Comment: Это что-то типа сортировки таблицы. Например, по имени или по фамилии, а другие столбцы подстраиваются под сортируемый.

Comment: Походу имеется ввиду многомерный массив.

Comment: Да, именно.

Comment: Я не знаю... приведите пример для понятности что ли...

Comment: Я так понимаю, есть массив:
    
    {
        {0,1, 2 }
        {1,2, 0 }
        {2,0, 1 }
    }

нужно отсортировать его по третьему столбцу, т.е.:

    {
        {1,2, 0 }
        {2,0, 1 }
        {0,1, 2 }
    }

верно понимаю?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

если требуется сортировать, как предложил [@Spectre](/users/3159/spectre), то особых проблем нет - берем за основу любую из видов сортировки одномерного массива. 

Сравниваем элементы T[i][3] и T[j][3], и в случае необходимости меняем i-ую и j-ую строку.

Answer (score 2):

Например для массива int x[n][m]; можно

```
qsort(x,n,sizeof(int)*m,xcmp);
....

int xcmp (const void *a, const void *b) 
{
  int *ax = (int *)a,
    *bx = (int *)b;

  return ax[3]-bx[3];

}
```

Comment: Только не забываем привести x к void*

Answer (score 2):

По мотивам ответа [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp) предлагаю такую функцию для сравнения

```
int xcmp (const void *a, const void *b) {
  return (int*)a[2]-(int*)b[2];
}
```

Заметьте - индекс==2, а не 3!

А для универсализма можно вообще сделать шаблон, чтобы для любых типов применять.