# Сортировка многомерного массива

Tags: c, алгоритм

Вопрос тот же, что и здесь:
[Сортировка многомерного массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/51378/c-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0)

Но ни один из предложенных вариантов не заработал. Может, есть готовые функции или можно как-нибудь с qsort нашаманить?

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <iostream>  

#define INF 1000
#define n 20
using namespace std;

int xcmp (const void *a, const void *b) 
{
  int *ax = (int *)a,
  *bx = (int *)b;

  return ax[0]-bx[0];

}
int main ()
{
int i, j, k=0;
int mas[3][27]={0};
/**************************
int cost[20][20] = {
    {0, 3, 6, 1, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF ,INF ,INF ,INF},//1
    {3, 0, INF, INF, 8, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF},//2
    {6, INF, 0, INF, INF, 7, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF},//3
    {1, INF, INF, 0, INF, 5, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF},//4
    {INF, 8, INF, INF, 0, INF, INF, 10, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, 4, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF},//5
    {INF, INF, 7, 5, INF, 0, 3, INF, INF, INF, 15, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF},//6
    {INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, 3, 0, INF, 12, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF},//7
    {INF, INF, INF, INF, 10, INF, INF, 0, 2, INF, INF, INF, INF, 1, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF},//8
    {INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, 12, 2, 0, 8, 7, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF},//9!!!
    {INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, 15, INF, INF, 8, 0, INF, INF, 9, INF, INF, INF, 17, INF, INF, INF},//10
    {INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, 7, INF, 0, 1, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF},//11
    {INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, 1, 0, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, 5, INF, INF},//12
    {INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, 9, 2, INF, 0, INF, INF, INF, 7, INF, INF, INF},//13
    {INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, 1, INF, INF, 3, INF, INF, 0, 5, 4, INF, INF, INF, INF},//14
    {INF, INF, INF, INF, 4, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, 5, 0, 2, INF, INF, INF, INF},//15
    {INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, 4, 2, 0, INF, 6, INF, INF},//16
    {INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, 17, INF, INF, 7, INF, INF, INF, 0, INF, 1, INF},//17
    {INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, 5, INF, INF, INF, 6, INF, 0, INF, 3},//18
    {INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, 1, INF, 0, 15},//19
    {INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, 3, 15, 0},//20
};
for (i=0; i<n-1; i++)
{
    for(j=i+1; j<n; j++)
    {
        if (cost[i][j]!=1000){
        //cout << cost [i][j] << " " << i << " " << j << endl;
        mas[0][k]=cost[i][j];
        mas[1][k]=i;
        mas[2][k]=j;
        k++;
        }
    }
}
******************************/
for (i=0; i<27; i++)
{
    cout << mas[0][i]<< " ";
    cout << mas[1][i] << " " << mas[2][i] << endl; 
}

cout << endl;

qsort(mas, 3, sizeof(int)*27, xcmp);

for (i=0; i<27; i++)
{
    cout << mas[0][i]<< " ";
    cout << mas[1][i] << " " << mas[2][i] << endl; 
}



getchar();

return 0;
```

}

Сверху - входные данные, снизу - выходные.
http://cs540109.vk.me/c620031/v620031450/1dd96/PKV5SEMBDy0.jpg
В закоменченном формируется исходный массив, можно не рассматривать.

Нужно отсортировать по первому столбцу, но чтобы двигалась вся строка.

Comment: @stupidmonkey, что именно не работает?

Код и тестовые данные в студию.

Comment: Ничего такого, но ник коду соответствует.

Comment: @stupidmonkey, а что Вы напечатать-то хотите?

--

Вы сортируете первые 3 строки. 

Правильно напечатать их (все 27 столбцов), наверное, проще (компактней) всего так:

     for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
       for (j = 0; j < 27; j++)
         printf("%d%c", mas[i][j], j == 26 ? '\n' : ' ');

А с сортировкой по нулевому столбцу тут все в порядке.

Comment: Тупанул, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю, на каком языке Вы программируете, но это определенно не C. Вот программа на C:

```
#include <stdlib.h>     // qsort
#include <stdio.h>      // printf

int linecmp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    int* line_a = *(int**)a;
    int* line_b = *(int**)b;
    return line_a[0] < line_b[0]? -1 : line_a[0] != line_b[0];
}

int main(void)
{
    const int array[3][3] = {
        { 4, 2, 3 },
        { 1, 9, 8 },
        { 7, 5, 6 }
    };

    int* lines[3];

    unsigned int i;
    for( i = 0; i < 3; ++i ) {
        lines[i] = (int*) &array[i][0];
    }

    qsort(lines, 3, sizeof(int*), linecmp);

    for( i = 0; i < 3; ++i ) {
        int* line = lines[i];
        printf("%d %d %d\n", *line++, *line++, *line);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Только вот это решение не той задачи.

Вы сортируете указатели на строки, а сам массив в памяти остается неизменным, а у ТС сорируются сами данные массива в памяти.